# Rails model caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, caching

I have two models, called `Division` and `Tier`, which are queried a lot, but inserts or updates are hardly ever done. The tables only have a handful or records in, so the whole tables can be stored in memory.

```
class Division
  # position: integer
  belongs_to :tier
end

class Tier
  # name: string
  has_many :tiers
end
```

These tables are queried in almost every page, so it seems like a waste of database calls

Model caching solutions like [identity cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache), which cache records in memcached, only allow you to retrieve records from the cache by id.

A lot of queries are just selecting by id, but I also perform a lot of queries like

```
SELECT * FROM divisions WHERE divisions.position BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I have a few questions

1. Will the database cache these tables in memory by itself, making another caching solution unnecessary?
2. If not, is there any way to cache these models in memory, and query against the cache using conditions other than just the id?
3. Am I essentially asking for something with the speed of redis/memcached, but the features of a relational database, which isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will cache models and avoid duplicate DB lookups but only for identical SQL queries, and only if that SQL query has already been made *in the same client request*.  So another caching solution may be warranted.

For your case (non-volatile, reference data), caching sounds like a good idea.  However, there are a few caveats:

- As you pointed out, you aren't always querying by id.  Which means that you either need to cache the results of given ranges (which seems like a bad idea), or you'll need a cache that can perform lookups by multiple indexes and find results across a range (`elasticsearch` would be a good example of this).
- Caches can become stale when you modify data (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).  Range caches are particularly vulnerable to this (another reason it was a bad idea), but even if you cache by indexes you'll still need to ensure that you update your caches accordingly.